# Why is GitKraken fast forwarding feature merges into the develop branch?

Tags: git, git-flow, gitkraken

GitKraken have what seems to be a nice built in UI to work with git flow. You can start and finish features, hotfixes and releases on a click of a button.

I was testing it in a local repo and I started a feature and made 3 commits to it. When I finished the feature (by clicking the GitKraken's finish button), the branch was merge with fast forward into the develop branch.

As far as I know this is not the expected behavior of git flow.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose either way, e.g. merge without fast-forwarding:

https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/CnLhpNuUkAAx4_6.mp4

(from https://twitter.com/gitkraken/status/752912345299464192)

Comment: I'm talking about the Git Kraken's built-in git flow helper mechanism. See this image: [link](https://imgur.com/ymYMIEM)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this in 2023:

GitKraken (as of 9.6.0) has an option when you click Finish, to rebase onto dev. If you leave that checked, all your commits will be moved to the dev branch as if they were committed there. If unchecked, it will show in the graph with the feature commits as separate from the dev branch. However, the commit messages themselves will still show in the dev branch on GitHub.

If you don't want your feature branch commit messages to show as part of your dev branch, select all the commits of your feature branch, right click and select Interactive Rebase. This will give you a chance to squash the commits into one (or several) with optionally rewording the commit. Then, you can do the "Finish" into dev (or main for a hotfix).